# Using replaceChild in predictive search feature

Tags: javascript, php, search

I'm trying to use .replaceChild to update a list of `<li>` every time I search. I'm returning an JSON object and turning it into an array from PHP. However using my current code I get : `Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node.`

JS:

```
function mainPageSearch() {
    var keyPressed = document.getElementById('main-page-search-input').value;
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var suggestions = document.querySelectorAll('.main-page-search-predictions')[0];
        for(i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
            var a = document.createElement('li');
            a.innerHTML = result[i];
            suggestions.replaceChild(a, suggestions);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', '/WEBSCRP/coursework/php/search.php?key='+keyPressed+'&func=mainsearch', true);
    xhr.send();

}
```

Originally, I have .appendChild and this worked but did not overwrite the previous search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.replaceChild()` is incorrect because the second argument must be the child of `suggestions` that is being replaced. Clearly `suggestions` can't be a child of itself.

To replace a child, you need to indicate which child node is being replaced. Otherwise how could it tell?

---

If you wanted to empty the list, then just do this  before using `.appendChild()`:

```
suggestions.innerHTML = ""
```

---

Or for a way to empty without using `.innerHTML`, do this:

```
while (suggestions.firstChild)
    suggestions.removeChild(suggestions.firstChild);
```

---

And FYI, you don't need `querySelectorAll` if you only want the first result. Use `querySelector` instead.

```
var suggestions = document.querySelector('.main-page-search-predictions');
```

---

---

So the final could look like this:

```
var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
var suggestions = document.querySelector('.main-page-search-predictions');
suggestions.innerHTML = "";

for(i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
    suggestions.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).innerHTML = result[i];
}
```

I shortened it just a bit by getting rid of the `a` variable.